How to reduce the default spacing between widget children in a column?
I was not able to find the answer to this question. I want to reduce the spacing between two widgets in a column.
Here is my code:
Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
                "image.png"),
            //----> Here is the spacing I want to reduce. <----<---
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 16),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Search here",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.filter),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  CustomSearchField(),
                ],
              ),

I have looked for other stackoverflow questions but the widgets were different and the solution to the question was dependent on the widgets. I have a image and widget between which I want to reduce the space.

There should be no spaces between the column children. It's most likely coming from the image not being fitted properly in the Image widget. It's also better if you can include the screenshot of the relevant widgets.

I was also thinking that image was the problem. Thanks.
